# Is necessary index a column of a table if is the last field on the query - MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, indexing

Suppose that i've a table (t1) with 3 columns (c1,c2,c3), and i added an index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `t1` ADD INDEX `IDX_c1_c2` USING BTREE (`c1`, `c2`);
```

I know that if i make this query use the index and works perfect:

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` where c1 = "foo" AND c2 = "bar"
```

But, what about this query?:

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` where c1 = "foo" AND c2 = "bar" AND c3 = "foobar"
```

The MySQL engine will use the index in order to improve the query or will ignore the index? i mean, the whole query must match with an index in order to use the index or may be i can take advantage of the index for the first two columns of the query.

[UPDATE] - The last query, in fact, look like this (the date is just an example):

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` where c1 = "foo" AND c2 = "bar" AND c3 > "2016-11-26 07:37:47"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make things simple your **exisiting index** will still be used , however third column will be resolved independently. The Query Processor will generate some plans and the best plan will be accepted by the engine to proceed . Still making third column an index as well will definitely boast the performance .

**Suggestion**
If you are using equality conditions in querying go for hash based indexing rather than Btree

Comment: Thanks for the answer, made me edit the post. Look at the update, the last query use an '>' operator for a date. I think that is not a good idea index a date so i want  refine the search with the first two columns and then Is much smaller the size of results to look by the date.

Comment: There are only two over head of indexes as far as i know . The write operation will take more time as more fields to update and more space will be consumed. Other than that i dont see a problem . If all three are run in the query i dont see a problem in making third column index as well . But if your system is working fine with existing design then don`t change it right now .

Comment: Hash indexes are only marginally faster than BTree for point queries.  But Hash is not available in MySQL.  (OK, there is a single exception.)

Answer (score 0):

[*This cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) provides all the answers to those questions, plus many more.

- `INDEX(c1, c2)` (in either order) works for all those cases;
- `(c1, c2, c3)` works for all those cases; and is better for 2nd and 3rd. Ditto for `(c2, c1, c3)`.
- Other orderings would not work well for your 3rd query -- the `=` parts must come first, not a 'range' (such as `>`)

Bonus:  If there really are only those 3 columns in the table, then `(c1, c2, c3)` is "covering".  That means that it can perform the entire query in the index BTree, and does not need to touch the data BTree.